# помогите создать функцию которая добавляет строку со словами в свойство массива

Tags: javascript

Создайте следующие функции:
• addWords (obj, wrds) - добавить строку со словами в свойство объекта.
Чтобы получилось как в примере

'

```
const obj = {
words: 'newspapers newspapers books magazines'
 };
console.log(obj); // {words: "newspapers newspapers books magazines"}
addWords(obj, 'radio newspapers ');
console.log(obj); // {words: "newspapers books magazines radio"}
```

'

Думаю,что это нужно сделать через Array.prototype.splice(),но не могу понять как именно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так можно думаю

```js
const obj = {
words: 'newspapers newspapers books magazines'
 };
console.log(obj); // {words: "newspapers newspapers  books magazines"}
addWords(obj, 'radio newspapers ');
console.log(obj); // {words: "newspapers books magazines radio"}


function addWords(obj, words) {
 obj.words = Array.from(new Set((obj.words + ' ' + words).split(" ").filter(item=>item!=""))).join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,все работает)